# How to bind a custom directive to all input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, directive

I have a custom directive called `HandleScroll` and I need to add this directive to all input elements. When I initially built it , it was only needed on one input elements so I added it manually as:

`< Input handle-scroll`....

But now I realize that I need to add this directive to each and every input element. Is there an easy way to do this using Javascript or will I have to sit and manually add this directive to each input tag ?

Update----Thank you everyone for your help, due to some updates I no longer need to use the directive , but need to bind an event listener to each input field. I've posted the new question at: [Adding an event listener to each input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654286/adding-an-event-listener-to-each-input-field) , if you can help please do , I greatly appreciate it !

Comment: you better explain what you want with this directive -- there might be better way

Answer (score 4):

In your directive class, you can set the selector in your decorator :

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input'
})
export class HandleScroll...
```

Comment: Hey Bernard , can you please elaborate ? Will this work on AngularJS and if I put this in my directive will it get called on every input field ?

Comment: It will work in Angular 2+ I believe, probably not in AngularJS. And yes with this selector, the directive will be applied to all your inputs. If your problem is related to AngularJS, you should change the tag in your question (Angular, not to be mistaken with AngularJS).

Comment: Oops my bad , needed a solution for AngularJS. Any suggestions for how to go about it if I'm using AngularJs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap input with angular component. And just use the component everywhere.

```
<app-input-with-directive></app-input-with-directive>
```

Comment: I already have around 400 input fields so it's not feasible for me to go and change each input and wrap the directive. I was hoping for some JS which selects each input and binds the directive to it

Comment: Most of IDEas can do it for you. Webstorm ctrl + shift + r opens replace menu. It will take less than minute. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS you can use following.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $compile, $window, $document) {
 $window.onload = function() {
    var inputs = $document[0].querySelectorAll('input');

  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.setAttribute('handle-scroll', true);

    $compile(input, $scope);
  });
 };
}
```

Basically, we are trying to add a new attribute to each input element on the page and recompiling the element.